# Generate a harmonic series: 1/1+1/2+1/3+...→∞. Generate this serie using a loop and print 100 iterations

Tags: r

```
harmsum <- 0 
for(k in 1:100) {
harmsum <- harmsum + 1/k
if (harmsum >= 100) break
print(harmsum)
}
```

I have tried this, but my output starts with 1 and it has to start with 0. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why should it start with 0? 1/1 = 1 and the value will increase after each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
harmsum <- 0 
for(k in 1:100) {
  print(harmsum)
  harmsum <- harmsum + 1/k
}
```